# find -exec doesn't do what find output suggests

Tags: find

If I do this `find`:

```
find ${TRIADS_DIR}/*.dc.results -path "*amblock/stats.*HEAD" -o -path "*amblock/stats.*BRIK"
```

then I get what I expect in STDOUT:

```
tp101.day1.dc.results/amblock/stats.tp101_day1+tlrc.HEAD
tp101.day1.dc.results/amblock/stats.tp101_day1+tlrc.BRIK
tp101.day2.dc.results/amblock/stats.tp101_day2+tlrc.HEAD
tp101.day2.dc.results/amblock/stats.tp101_day2+tlrc.BRIK
...
```

If I add an `-exec` clause to link the found files:

```
find ${TRIADS_DIR}/*.dc.results -path "*amblock/stats.*HEAD" -o -path "*amblock/stats.*BRIK" -exec ln -s {} ${TRIADS_GROUP} \;
```

then it only links the BRIKs:

```
stats.tp101_day1+tlrc.BRIK@
stats.tp101_day2+tlrc.BRIK@
...
```

#### Questions

- What's happening?
- Is there a more efficient way to tell find to return .HEAD and .BRIK using a single wildcard expression? I tried things like:

  ```
  find ${TRIADS_DIR}/*.dc.results -path "*amblock/stats.*{HEAD,BRIK}"
  ```

  but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1: What's happening?

Your `-o` is splitting your arguments. The `-exec` only runs if the stuff on the same side of the `-o` is successful (the `-path "*amblock/stats.*BRIK"`). If you want `-exec` to run on both conditions, you need to wrap them in parenthesis:

```
find ${TRIADS_DIR}/*.dc.results \( -path "*amblock/stats.*HEAD" -o -path "*amblock/stats.*BRIK" \) -exec ln -s {} ${TRIADS_GROUP} \;
```

### Question 2: Is there a more efficient way to tell find to return .HEAD and .BRIK using a single wildcard expression?

No, kinda. Some `find` implementations have a `-regex` non-standard predicate which you could use instead, but I wouldn't call that "more efficient".